# How to detect when OS X Screen Sharing is active programmatically?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, growl, screensharing

OS X does not make it obvious that you might've left a screen sharing session open -- and it's still actively broadcasting your session to these other computers.  **Does anyone know where Snow Leopard stores that the computer you're sitting at has an open screen sharing session?**

If I could detect this file using a shell script every minute or so, then I could fire a Growl notification to let me know that I'm essentially being watched by this other computer (using the code snippet found [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071009124425468)).

Otherwise, the only way to know now is to notice a very small icon on the top right of my screen that looks like binoculars (very hard to notice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use lsof to check for any established connections by AppleVNCServer

```
lsof -a -i :vnc-server -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -c AppleVNCServer
```